# how to change color of inner div with opacity of 1 with a wrapper div

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to change the color of inner div with the opacity of 1 with a wrapper div?

I am able to achieve this with background color if the opacity is 0 but once the opacity is put to 1 it is not working. I am understanding why it is happening but not sure how to fix it.

```
<div id="div2" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div id= "div1"  style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255,1) "></div>
</div>
```

```
$("#div2").css("background-color", 'rgba(235, 235, 228,1)')
```

I cannot control the inner div which is having an opacity of 1 but I want give  this (rgb(235, 235, 228)) color (disabled look) for the inner div when needed. I trying to achive with a wrapper.

Comment: Your code has jQuery

Answer (score 0):

a) Addressing the div (div1) inside div2:

```
$("#div2 div").css( … )
```

b) or directly addressing div1:

```
$("#div1").css( … )
```

Comment: I should not change the #div1 opacity to make my functionality working in #div1. So i  need a disabled look  with out touching it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do need a wrapper for ? Just use this for the div you want to disable:

```
<div id="div1"  style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255,1) "></div>

$("#div1").css({
    "background-color", 'rgba(235, 235, 228)',
    "pointer-events", "none"
 });
```

**Update**

```js
$('.disable').on('click', function(){
     $("#div1").addClass("disabled-control");
});

$('.enable').on('click', function(){
     $("#div1").removeClass("disabled-control");
});
```

```css
.disabled-control {
    background-color : rgba(235, 235, 228) !important;
    pointer-events : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div2" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div id= "div1"  style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255,1) "></div>
</div>

<br><br>
<button class="disable">Disable</button>   <button class="enable">Enable</button>
```

Comment: As i said in question I cannot control the Inner div(div1). I have to do this with out touching it. but one thing i know is ,it  is having opacity of 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. you are making the #div1 opacity to '0' by adding the .disabled-control. I need to have #div1 opacity to '1' and then give a disabled look. looking for something like  foreground color instead of background color if it make scene